# Jackson @JsonView in Kotlin throwing MissingKotlinParameterException

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I'm playing around with Kotlin, Jackson and @JsonView Annotation.

Following POJO or POKO, however and a tiny json file :)

```
{
  "Name": "Tester Fred",
  "SecretText": "930479756",
  "Address": "21.,MeineGasse 56-60",
  "Validto": "\/Date(1584748033000)\/"
}
```

```kotlin
class PlayingWithViews(
        @JsonView(TestViews.NameAndAddress::class)
        val name: String,
        val secretText: String,
        @JsonView(TestViews.NameAndAddress::class)
        val address: String,
        @JsonDeserialize(using = DateToLongSerializer::class)
        val validto: Long)

class TestViews {
    interface NameAndAddress
}
```

with the following Test

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `test JsonView Annotation`() {
        val jsonContent = readFromResources("plain.json")

        val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
                .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
                .disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION)

        val detailed = mapper.readerWithView(TestViews.NameAndAddress::class.java)
                .forType(PlayingWithViews::class.java)
                .readValue<PlayingWithViews>(jsonContent)

        assertThat(detailed).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("address", "21.,MeineGasse 56-60")
        assertThat(detailed).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("name", "Tester Fred")
    }
```

When I run the test it always throws following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class at.xyz.jacksonmapper.model.PlayingWithViews] value failed for JSON property SecretText due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter secretText which is a non-nullable type
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "Name": "Tester Fred",
  "SecretText": "930479756",
  "Address": "21.,MeineGasse 56-60",
  "Validto": "\/Date(1584748033000)\/"
}
"; line: 6, column: 1] (through reference chain: at.xyz.jacksonmapper.model.PlayingWithViews["SecretText"])
```

I'm not getting the problem with the "SecretText" property. Jackson shouldn't even consider it due to not being annotated with `@JsonView`-Annotation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue, were you able to find a fix for this?